# Shortest distance from point to curve

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I could use some help solving the following problem. I have many more like this but I figured if I learn how to do one then I can figure out the rest on my own. Thanks in advance!

> A curve described by the equation $y=\sqrt{16x^2+5x+16}$ on a Cartesian plane. What is the shortest distance between coordinate $(2,0)$ and this line?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means for a line to *follow a curve*?  Is the question simply to find the shortest distance between $(2,0)$ and that curve?

Comment: the equation of the line. ill edit to clear that up. thx

Comment: yes, the solution would be to find the shortest distance between the point (2,0) and the curve

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start by finding the distance from some point on the curve to $(2,0)$ in terms of $x$. Using the distance formula, we get
$$D=\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(\sqrt{16x^2+5x+16}-0)^2}$$
$$D=\sqrt{x^2-4x+4+16x^2+5x+16}$$
$$D=\sqrt{17x^2+x+20}$$
This will end up being a messy derivative. However, since the distance $D$ will never be negative, we can minimize $D^2$ instead of $D$ and still get the same answer. So now we get
$$D^2=17x^2+x+20$$
$$\frac{dD^2}{dx}=34x+1$$
Now we set this equal to $0$ and solve for $x$:
$$34x+1=0$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{34}$$
So the distance is minimized at $x=-\frac{1}{34}$, and to find the minimum distance, simply evaluate $D$ when $x=-\frac{1}{34}$.

Comment: Let's suppose that D can be negative, then can we still simplify using $D^2$?

Comment: @PianoLand No, but there is something wrong with your D formula if you can't do that.

Answer (score 4):

Since distance is positive and the square root function is increasing, it suffices to find the smallest value the squared distance between $(x,y)$ on the curve and the point $(2,0)$ can take. This is
$$ L(x) = (x-2)^2 + (y-0)^2 = (x-2)^2+y^2 = x^2-4x+4 + 16x^2+5x+16 = 17x^2+x+20. $$
A minimum can only occur if $L'(x)=0$. So
$$ L'(x) = 34x+1, $$
so there is a turning point at $x=-1/34$. Moreover, the derivative is negative on the left and positive on the right, so the point is a minimum. Hence the minimum distance is
$$ \sqrt{L(-1/34)} = \sqrt{\frac{1359}{68}} \approx 4.47. $$

Comment: Why not a negative $x$?

Comment: Brain fart. Thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: Truly an anomaly from someone with a 33.5k reputation!

Comment: Let us hope so!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**: take a point $(x, y)$ *on the curve*, calculate its distance from $(2, 0)$. The fact that the point is *on the curve* allows you to express that distance in terms of $x$ alone. Then find the minimum (but check the second hint first).

**Hint 2**: instead of minimizing the distance, minimize the *square* of the distance.