# Minimum distance between a point and an ellipse

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, conic-sections, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to use Lagrange multiplier method to find the minimum distance between a given point $P(h,k)$ and the given ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ occurs when the circle centered with $P$ touches the ellipse.

So my objective function is to minimize:
$$f(x, y)=(x-h)^{2}+(y-k)^{2}$$
Subject to constraint:
$$g(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1=0$$
We have:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\overrightarrow{\nabla f}=2(x-h) \hat{i}+2(y-k) \hat{j} \\
\overrightarrow{\nabla g}=\frac{2 x}{a^{2}} \hat{i}+\frac{2 y}{b^{2}} \hat{j}
\end{array}$$
If $\lambda$ is the lagrange multiplier, we have:
$$\begin{aligned}
\overrightarrow{\nabla f} &=\lambda \overrightarrow{\nabla g} \\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{a^{2}(x-h)}{x} &=\frac{b^{2}(y-k)}{y}=\lambda
\end{aligned}$$
Now eliminating $\lambda$ is too tedious for me. Any way to solve here?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264702/shortest-distance-from-point-to-curve

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2090289/339790).